# Spotify Playlist URl

Tags: ios5, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I'm working with Spotify. I've Spotify playlist with me. Now the question is how to obtain the url from that playlist in order to play the song??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SPPlaylist` has a `spotifyURL` property, as does `SPTrack` (and pretty much every other metadata object).

Comment: Hi! iKenndac .Thank You for your answer. But can you please elaborate this in detail?